# Extract a .ff files (fast files) to view .gsc files inside using C#

Tags: c#

I want to extract a `.ff` files (*fast files*) to view `.gsc` files inside using `C#`. I can't find any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to extract with 7z. Here's a library that helps extract 7z compatible archives: https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: If there is no problem. Can you help me with the code here? I tried but not working, showing error:   A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Desktop\common.ff' because it is being used by another process.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Please refer to "Quick start" section on Home tab. They have included code samples as well. Try yourself and come up with specific issues, if any.

Comment: downvote? I don't think i guided OP in wrong direction.